# How to get the zero based indexes all sub-menus in a CMenu object

Tags: c++, mfc, win32com

I have a CMenu instance. I would like to dynamically traverse all menu and sub-menu items in the menu.

The API for getting a sub-menu is called CMenu::GetSubMenu. Its lone parameter is the sub-menu's position (zero based index) within the parent menu.

How do I get the positions of all sub-menus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`CMenu::GetMenuItemCount()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxha0csx.aspx) to determine the number of menu items. Iterate over the menu items, calling [`CMenu::GetSubMenu(nPos)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtfc356x.aspx) for each to determine whether that menu item has a submenu (i.e. the call does not return `NULL`).